# Does browserindocker() or watch() support recording of browser in docker execution in headless mode?

Tags: java, docker, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

I'm trying to video record the browser activities in container execution. Does browserindocker.enableRecording() or watch() apis in Boni gracia webdriver manager 5.6.2 support it?

I have been trying to video record the browser activities in java framework

Answer (score 1):

WebDriverManager allows to record the session of a dockerized browser using the method `enableRecording()` together with `browserInDocker()`. You can find the explanation and examples in the documentation:

https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/#recordings

Comment: I really appreciate your quick response.I'm trying to run my framework in a docker container (orchestrator pipeline). When I add browserInDocker() I see the below warning: There was a problem executing command docker info n the shell. Can you please let me know if there is any other option to video record browser activities in a container